# How to count ordinal values through multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in R that looks like this:

```
User <-c('User_1','User_2','User_3','User_4','User_5')
Q1 <- c('Never', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Often', 'Always') 
Q2<- c('Sometimes', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Often', 'Rarely')
Q3 <- c('Always', 'Rarely', 'Sometimes', 'Always', 'Rarely')
data1 <- data.frame(User, Q1, Q2, Q3)
print(data1)

Output
    User        Q1        Q2        Q3
1 User_1     Never Sometimes    Always
2 User_2    Rarely    Rarely    Rarely
3 User_3 Sometimes Sometimes Sometimes
4 User_4     Often     Often    Always
5 User_5    Always    Rarely    Rarely
```

My goal is to count how many times the values 'Never', and 'Always' appear in each row. So the output would look something like this. How should I go about this? Thank you!

```
  User      Never    Always        
  User_1      1         1      
  User_2      0         0              
  User_3      0         0 
  User_4      0         1    
  User_5      0         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `rowSums` with `across`:
With `across` we apply `rowSums` to each column `(, ~..)` and count `Never` and `Always` for each row:

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
  mutate(Never = rowSums(across(, ~ .x == "Never")),
         Always = rowSums(across(, ~ .x == "Always"))) %>%
  select(User, Never, Always)

   User Never Always
1 User_1     1      1
2 User_2     0      0
3 User_3     0      0
4 User_4     0      1
5 User_5     0      1
```